# HTML PHP Form Upload .doc and .docx only

Tags: html, forms, file, file-upload

I need some help with my syntax. I need the possibility to upload either .doc or .docx files. But I dont know how to go about it. Please see my code:

```
//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["datafile"])) && ($_FILES['datafile']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 2mb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['datafile']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "docx,doc") && ($_FILES["datafile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") && 
    ($_FILES["datafile"]["size"] < 2100000)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           $sasquach = "The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
           $link= 'http://orchardsystems2012.co.za/'.$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].'/upload/'.$filename;
        } else {
           //echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         //echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["datafile"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     //echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 2mb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 //echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.....
    if (in_array($ext, array("docx", "doc")
      && (in_array($_FILES["datafile"]["type"], array("application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))
....
```

see other types [here](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

Comment: But why If I replace this bit: if (($ext == "docx,doc") till ($_FILES["datafile"]["size"] < 2100000)) { it doesnt work?

Comment: @brett does not work what? any errors?

Comment: Sorry mate yeah got it working now - thanks just did it a different way... I'm no PHP expert so I ask a lot of questions now I cant ask questions because some douche downvoted me... ah well